# Returning a function from a function without calling the returned function

Tags: javascript, function

Can it be done?

I have the following:

```
populate.func = function(node, state) {
    return (new function(data) { /* stuff*/ });
}
```

However, calling populate.func invariably calls both the called function and the returned function, whether I use regular calling convention or the call method.  I want to be able to call populate.func and just return the function as a value to make use of, without actually running it...

Comment: why `new`? it should work without it.
i mean, say `infunc = function(data){ /* stuff*/ };` You do:
`return infunc;`

Comment: You want to return the function as a string?

Comment: New because I read that this was a trick to pass a function by reference and pass variable in the state it was in when you passed the function as an argument, and not when it gets called.  I think it does this because so long as a pointer is maintained to the child function, the parent can't be garbage collected either, nor its call stack.  Or something.

Comment: @RobF you have been terribly misinformed, go read up some more on javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this

```
populate.func = function(node, state) {
    return (function(data) { /* stuff*/ });
}
```

Your code is instantiating a new object using your function as a constructor function, but you want to return a reference to your function instead, so just drop the new keyword.

Comment: That seems to have worked.  Will wait and experiment a bit before leaving feedback.  Why did new operator cause it to call both functions?

Comment: because you executed the function to instantiate an object from it, using the function as a constructor function.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @RobF It does, that is exactly the reason why it calls the function. You should read up on what [new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) does in JS.

Comment: @RobF do you feel like you understand what i tried to say or is it still unclear ?

Comment: @helmus: It's clear now.  I thought the new operator used the return value of the function rather than the function itself.

I also didn't catch on that the constructor was in fact, that; I thought it was a definition of one specific function (thinking it analogous to struct { blah;} var; in C ), hence my feeling the need for the new operator to make copies of it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure what your code is actually doing, but I think what you want is:

```
populate.func = function(node, state) {
    return function(data) { /* stuff*/ };
}
```

Comment: @RobF adding in new doesn't make any diffrence there, you are returning an object by reference, instantiated by your constructor function, but not the function it self.

Comment: `return function...` will return a reference to the function w/o executing it.